# Can "is it not that" be used as an equivalent of "is it not the case that"?

Tags: expressions

I think I encountered the phrase "is it not that," in a context where it meant "is it not the case that."

For instance, would "Is it not that fire burns?" be an equivalent of "Is it not the case that fire burns?"?

If so, isn't this formulation excessively formal / archaic?

Comment: Yes, it would and yes, it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Wouldn't it be somewhat less archaic in the following context : "If it is claimed that A, is it not that B?," meaning "If it is claimed that A, does it not follow that B?"